# Android: Intent-Filter and Web Page in Background

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a web page that I want to detect my Android App (**in background**) using intent-filter of course, so my App and my page do their work separately.

My android application handles a URL like the URL below using intent-filter:

```
myApp://sample?param=1
```

So I have an `<a>` tag in my page which I clicked it using JavaScript (automatically):

```
<a href="myApp://sample?param=1" id="myAppLink"></a>
```

Everything works fine exept when I don't have my App installed (for example in PC or iOS).
In this situation the browser redirects to `myApp://sample?param=1` (naturally).

Is there any way (in JavaScript I think) that I can detect if the app not handled my URL then I stop automatic clicking? Or other way (tricks of course) to know if the App installed then I call click event? Or some other workarounds to my problem?

Or can I call my URL (`myApp://sample?param=1`) using AJAX or JSONP so my App detects it?
(I've tried this with jQuery Ajax without a chance. I don't know if the intent-filter could handle Ajax requests.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot check from the web if any applications is installed on the device, because of privacy issues.

See similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856773/detect-if-android-app-has-been-installed-on-the-device-using-a-mobile-web-page).

Comment: Of course we cannot check that. But I need a tricky way with intent-filter if anyone has any idea...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can identify an intent pointing to your server link, using http:// instead of myApp:// :

```
<data android:host="yourhost.com" data android:path="/apath" android:scheme="http" />
```

for ...

```
<a href="http://yourhost.com/apath?param=1" id="myAppLink"></a>
```

If your app exists it will redirect to the app (the user will need to confirm the first time), if not, it will call the link where you host a page that will answer properly for desktop (using PHP, java, nodejs, or whatever).