# how to open mobile chrome browser with javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, android-intent, deeplink

I have two questions.

**//// I want this ////**

I want to open chrome browser with url on other android mobile webapp(ex naver, firefox, etc...) with using javascript or html

so example)
if user click MysiteButton on mobile web app, then open android device mobile chrome browser with redirect url(on chrome).

what should i do.

**//// Question List ////**

1. i found that I should use deeplink or intent but i don't know android mobile chromebrower's intent url or Scheme url.
   what is android mobile chromebrower's intent url. how to get.
   ( i used  window.location.href = "market://detail?id=com.android.chrome"; but not worked)
2. when i use deeplink or intent, how to redirect url on chrome at the same time open chrome

Comment: Duplicate question, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29673757/3424327

Comment: thank you answer. but maybe it is different.

I want open anroid chrome brower from other browers(ex firebox brower not my build app) with javascript or html ( if click my homepage button )

Comment: Web apps that run in browsers ie Firefox/Chrome are sandboxed and do not interact with the system. You can't open for example your camera through a browser. The only way as far as I know to open chrome is to be the default browser.

Comment: thank you! i resolve that other way

Comment: @minsulee please tell us how You did. I need it too

Answer (score 6):

For Android:

```
<a href="intent:https://yourwebsite.com#Intent;end" target="_blank">Open Browser</a>
```

Note: This solution will open default browser (if its set, if no default browser set, it will show list of browsers which supports opening url)

Make sure that, the click is generated by user (Not Javascript) to test this. Some browsers wont open if its NOT called by user.

Comment: I have been looking for an answer like this for a while... thanks! I tried it out on my pixel now to look for an iOS equivalent. Thanks! ❤️

Comment: Do you know if there is an equivelant solution for IOS?

Comment: Hey John, Thanks a lot. Will it work on iOS too?

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the answer too as I've tried to send my users from unsupported browsers (for ex: Facebook browser) to chrome.

Unfortunately, John's solution didn't work for me but it pointed in the right direction.

What works for me:

```
<a href="intent://mysite.com#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end">
    Click to open on Chrome
  </a>
```

### Explanation

I've found a good explanation at https://branch.io/glossary/chrome-intents/ , but to sum it up:

Split it to 3 vars:

URI: the name of the site (ex: google.com), and notice its without the UriSchemes.

UriSchemes: HTTP / https (you can read more about it at https://www.w3.org/wiki/UriSchemes)

PACKAGE: the package of the app we want to send the intent to, in our case its com.android.chrome

now you can just insert them in the code below

```
<a href="intent://URI#Intent;scheme=UriSchemes;package=PACKAGE">
    Click to open on Chrome
  </a>
```

Comment: First answer on StackOverflow btw. Yay!

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following, It worked for me:

```
"googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url

i.e. window.open("googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url,"_system"); // here you can try with _system or _blank as per your requirement
```

Comment: your solution throw an error. Not allowed to load local resource: googlechrome://navigate?url=www.myurl.com