# Redirect from in-app-browser to Google Chrome on Android using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to redirect users from the SnapChat browser to Google Chrome when using an Android Phone.

I have followed the instructions recommending I use this:

[Phonegap - How to open external link inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737582/phonegap-how-to-open-external-link-inside-the-app)

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_system')">`

This follows the link, but keeps me in the in-app-browser.

Further research, however, shows me that '_sytem is relegated just to Cordova etc.

Any suggestions as to how to exit to Google Chrome?

I followed [JS - Mobile - Open Safari from any browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025910/js-mobile-open-safari-from-any-browser) and was able to do this successfully on iOS to Safari.

Comment: I need know too. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android only, you can do this:

```
googlechrome://navigate?url=https://intaface.me/rcv/764e184b-4a43-466e-ae24-12dc14f8684b
```

For general approach of opening default browser while on in-app browser, you can follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066226/9814737