# intents on the Snapchat browser on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent, snapchat

I'm trying to create a link within the Android SnapChat browser that will launch in Google Chrome.

I have this code from [What is the intent to launch any website link in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250152/what-is-the-intent-to-launch-any-website-link-in-google-chrome):

```
<a href="intent://stackoverflow.com#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end"> Launch Site </a>
```

This works when tested in Google Chrome, but it does not redirect nor open Google Chrome as hoped in the Snapchat browser?

Is it possible to launch this link in Google Chrome?