# How to open google chrome from webview via javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webview, inappbrowser

I am having a website in which i am using api's like push notification ,but when anyone open via Facebook or Twitter they tend to load an Android webview in which push notification api's are not there, the hack which i found is that if i can open chrome from webview in this way my push notification would work

it had tried

```
window.open("googlechrome://navigate?url=" + location.href, "_system")
```

but this gives error as *Not allowed to load local resource:*

need help from you all

Comment: did you tried this way?  window.open("googlechrome://navigate?url=" + location.href,'_system','location=yes');

Comment: @Shoma,tried ,same error

Comment: what do you store in "location.href"?

Comment: It gives u the current url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As posted over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229510/url-scheme-to-open-chrome-firefox-android-os-from-facebook-post) use the below code

```
window.location = 'intent:https://example.com#Intent;end';
```

Comment: Is this opens in chrome ? I cant find working one in 2021.

Comment: @user3304007 worked for me in Instagram and Facebook Messenger webviews, it opens the default browser (in my case — Chrome)

Comment: Did you find a working one ?