# How to work around lack WebRTC support in a browser?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, user-experience

Some browsers (mobile Mi Browser, for instance) don't support WebRTC - they have no RTCPeerConnection API. So the users of your WebRTC web app have to open it in another one.
Is there a way to make your WebRTC app work without an explicit browser-change action from the user, especially on a mobile device?

I tried to investigate the following:

1. Deep Link. Looks like we can't redirect the user to another browser using deep link (I haven't found Chrome deep link for mobile).
2. Send WebRTC sources to browser / use third-party WebRTC lib. This won't work either, you need WebRTC support in the browser source code.

Comment: If the browser doesn't support it, then no, there's not much you can do. Certain browsers or certain OSes/apps may have some specific link schema you can use to directly switch to a supported browser, but that's few and far between and case by case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRTC is a framework based on a set of standards. It includes not only capability to get information about user input/output devices, but also set of network protocols which based on **UDP** (from getting client's IP to transfer arbitrary data through data channel using SCTP protocol). So, as you already may guess, it's impossible to support in a browser which doesn't have it, this is why point (2) will not work.

In case of point (1 - Open Chrome). On iOS exists custom protocol to open URL in chrome "googlechromes://stackoverflow.com", but it's better to explicitly say user that current browser doesn't support required functionality; And provide links on list of popular browsers for download (Chrome, Firefox, etc.); And already on these websites user will be redirected to the proper store for downloading native app.

Comment: Do you know custom protocol to open URL in chrome for Xiaomi? I haven't found it on google...

Comment: @EugeneF. Try to use "intent" https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/ | https://stackoverflow.com/a/29673757/1620380