# Android qr code download the app if not installed

Tags: android, qr-code

I'm in a development of an Android app which uses a REST API in a server. In the request it needs a number and an API endpoint, e.g.:

http://apilocation/endpoint/number

What I'd like to do is to make a QR code, that will download the app from Google Play if it's not installed, or if it's installed then it'll open up the app with the required parameters. Is it possible somehow, or I should put a QR code reader activity in the app, and the users have to use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856773/detect-if-android-app-has-been-installed-on-the-device-using-a-mobile-web-page) which could be cool for you. And this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pulletsforever/2662899) could help you, it's pretty well done and, on your side, you need to define an `Intent Filter` in order that your app could be triggered by the `custom-protocol` of the JS I put a link of.

Comment: You're welcome! I did something similar one and half year ago. I found that it gives a really good user experience!