# How to detect if mobile apps has been already installed with JS or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mobile

I have some tasks to make a link on mobile site.
The link lets user to download mobile apps.
But there is some conditions about the link.
If user has already installed mobile apps, the link will open mobile apps and show the same page like mobile site.
But if user hasn't already installed yet, the link will open Google Store or Apple Store to download mobile apps.

Is it posibble to do it?
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856773/detect-if-android-app-has-been-installed-on-the-device-using-a-mobile-web-page