# Check if app is existing on device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, deep-linking

I need to check if app is installed on iPhone or android device, using javascript code only. As i am working on html website.

I have used

```
window.location="appname://";
```

but it makes me to open an app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully, this is not possible, for obvious privacy reasons.

Comment: I hope that there is no way, cause I don't want any website know which apps I am using.

Comment: Is "appname" your own app?

Comment: if you open quora.com on your mobile device browser. It shows bottom badge to open an app if installed or not then goes to app store.

Comment: there is some website which provide this functionality for ex. yelp.com , naukri.com etc @CommonsWare

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments there are security and privacy reasons surrounding why you are not able to do what you are asking.

However, [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), has already given a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12857967/4180965) to this problem, in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12856773/4180965), that has already been asked:

> Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy reasons.
>
> The closest that you can do is in the application, have an activity
>   that has an  for some URL structure, and have a link in
>   the mobile Web site to a matching URL.
>
> If the user clicks the link and the app is installed, the activity
>   will be a chooser option for the user.
>
> If the user clicks the link and the app is not installed, or they
>   choose to stick with their Web browser from the chooser, whatever Web
>   page exists at that URL will be displayed (E.g., instructions of how
>   to download the app).