# Android custom scheme on intent-filter link

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am writing new feature to my small app, the ability to share items.
For that I want to implement custom scheme like `myApp://share/PARENT/CHILD`
.
I searched for it here and on the web, finding small pieces of info, but not usable stuff.
Once I am adding the intent-filter to my Manifest, the app can be opened by browser links like:
`<a href="myApp://share/PARENT/CHILD">CLICK</a>` .

But, once I am sharing the link with `sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);` and sharing with WhatsApp or Gmail for example, the link is not clickable.

After searching here i read about ***Linkify*** but I did understand that it probably will not help me here (because the regex is already fine).

So my questions is:

1. Is it possible to use non-http schemes as links on Android apps?
2. If (1) is false, how can I achieve this with http scheme? Can I set my app as default for scheme + host specifications?
3. Can I tell the app store to open in case my App is missing? [I assume this is achievable only with http schemes, right?]

Thank you.

Comment: Did you every figure out a solution for this? Wrestling with the same problem now and can't see a way out of it

Comment: Not yet, sorry :-(

Comment: thanks anyway.  2 options on my end: going with having the app intercept *.<domain>.com/<path> in the intent filter or having the server (if you control the site) issue a redirect to your app's scheme. I *think* that will result in your app being launched

Comment: You are right, but launching it from the web server cannot help if the app is not installed, I need a way to the website to know if the app installed or not, if not I'll link to the market, if yes I'll launce with the scheme..

Comment: What about these? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12901352/2851084 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone

Comment: Are you talking about a ContentProvider?

Comment: What do you mean by contentProvider?