# I am trying to open an android app from browser. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, deep-linking

This is my code :

```
 window.location.href = 'intent://#Intent;package=mypackagename;scheme=myscheme;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%3Fhl%3Den;end;';
```

This is present in the AndroidManifest.xml of the android app:

```
<intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
</intent-filter>
```

It is saying "Invalid operation". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app

Comment: Yes I have. Doesn't seem to work. My android version is lollipop.

Comment: Read this https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html there is no matter for android version

Comment: this is use full for you to better understand look all answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888867/detect-from-browser-if-a-specific-application-is-installed-in-android

Comment: Thanks @Hasmukhkachhatiya for the references. However, I have been to all of them and have been through hell and back trying the various suggestions in other SO posts, no use so far!

Comment: there is correct answer also said it is not possible but in below there is 83+ answer also show the another way