# Android Intent filter for url with redirect

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

How to setup intent filter for url with redirection?

https://mail.mailserverXXX.com/m/redirect?url=http://foosubdomain.foodomain.com/#object?id=e1162d22-222b-4522-2210-c222102d6022

This filter does not work for URL above.

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:host="foosubdomain.foodomain.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This filter works for URL above. But this is not what needed. I need to filter by host in redirect part *foosubdomain.foodomain.com*

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:host="mail.mailserverXXX.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well bad news. After a long check I found that `intent-filter` doesnt even parse everything after question mark

In other words from link

> https://mail.mailserverXXX.com/m/redirect?url=http://foosubdomain.foodomain.com/#object?id=e1162d22-222b-4522-2210-c222102d6022

`Intent-filter` works only with that part

> https://mail.mailserverXXX.com/m/redirect

So there is **impossible** to write universal solution for your problem.

Comment: It does not work or I'm wrong somewhere. I also do not need to mention the specific mail server in the filter.

Comment: DEADMC, thanks for the help. Unfortunately, the mail server adds a redirect to the URLs.

Comment: @pier_nasos but after you click redirect link you will open your site, right? You can add one more parameter like mobileRedirect=true to your url and then force to open mobile app from site.

Comment: The site is also there and it performs the same tasks as the mobile application. In a good way, when clicking on a link, I need to open the application, if it is installed, otherwise - open the site. But the site can not determine if the application is installed.

Comment: @pier_nasos actually site can =) check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888867/detect-from-browser-if-a-specific-application-is-installed-in-android