# Html: Open ios application by href link

Tags: android, html, swift, android-intent, href

I use below code for `android` and work fine :

```
href='intent://name.com#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.name.app;S.POSITION=handle;end'
```

But for `ios` i can't find `href` solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer below flow of ios and web for implementing this in IOS.

IOS ::In Info.plist add a **URL Types** for example "SomeIdentification". (you can add hostname of your site)

WEB :: Your app will now open when you strike  "SomeIdentification://" in safari. If you are using any other link then you need to detect ios devcie and trigger "SomeIdentification://" onclick of URL.
[For more detail of ios you can refer](https://kitefaster.com/2016/07/13/how-to-open-ios-app-with-custom-url/)