# Open app if installed, otherwise open in google play store. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, android

I have a website, and I have a popup that asks if you want to use the app instead of the browser. If you click "Open (my website name) in the app" I want it to open my app If It's installed. Otherwise, open the google playstore link for it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect from browser if a specific application is installed in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888867/detect-from-browser-if-a-specific-application-is-installed-in-android)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try, and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: Deeplinks on android are handled by system level intents, so you can add an intent filter on your android app, and a corresponding server implementation for a given url.  Then your JS just tries to open one URL, and the android system will handle the rest.

A more complete answer is here:

[Detect from browser if a specific application is installed in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888867/detect-from-browser-if-a-specific-application-is-installed-in-android)

Note that the "answer" to that question is not where the info is - its in the most upvoted response though.